# FromStr::from_str() изнутри

Tags: строки, rust

Как в расте работает `FromStr::from_str()`? В [исходниках](https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/str/trait.FromStr.html#tymethod.from_str) только пустая функция `from_str()` в трейте `FromStr`, а так же парсер `bool`. Как происходит преобразование строки в `u64`, например?

Answer (score 2):

Я бы грепнул "impl FromStr" по исходникам просто - https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/search?l=rust&q=impl+FromStr.

Реализация для u64 - https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/9da7706dd64/src/libcore/num/mod.rs#L1326-L1337

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы ссылки не добавляют знаний в Рунет.

Comment: Сама функция, интересующая автора вопроса, тут https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/9da7706dd64/src/libcore/num/mod.rs#L1365

Comment: @ozkriff этот ответ должен был бы быть комментарием.

Comment: Виноват, учту :)